# Error trying to set the url for a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have the following code:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
pane.setPage("http://www.google.com");
```

the setPage gives me the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.google.com

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I tried this code here and works fine. You have firewall / proxy configured? Interesting that the url of the error is checkupdown and not google.

Comment: @SérgioMichels sorry the checkupdown  is a typo error. Apparently I was blocked by the firewall.

Comment: @SérgioMichels post your comment as a answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, posting as answer:

This can be a firewall or proxy block. I've tried the code here and works fine.